# How to find word or number with $search_string

Tags: php, exact-match

For a function `$search_string` I want to extract an exact word (here number) from a file.
If for example in my text file I have these lines:

```
file1: 2 file2: 23 file3: 32
```

then with the command `$search_string = "file1";`  I get result of `file1` be "2" while I want that if I make a `$search_string = "file2";`
it takes me the result of `file2` be "23".

How can I modify this code or other piece of code to extract an exact word or number from a text file?

```
file.txt :

file1: 2
file2: 23
file3: 32
```

```
<?php 
$lines_array = file("file.txt");
$search_string = "file2";
foreach($lines_array as $line)
{
if(strpos($line, $search_string) !== false)
{
list(, $new_str) = explode(":", $line);
}
}
echo $new_str;
?>
```

Comment: Does your text file have multiple lines or one single line? You have wrote both cases in your question, so it is not clear which case it is.